# How to use Goutte without cookie

Tags: php, goutte

How to use [goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte) but don't send cookies back to the server?

I want to do that because the server can manage sessionid in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I end up using [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [browserkit](https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit) directly without using goutte. Guzzle let you chose to manage or not cookies http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies.

This solved this problem amount others.

If really you like goutte, I guess you can also delete cookie between each requests.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I see is to instantiate the GuzzleClient yourself and pass it to the Goutte client.

Like this:

```
use Goutte\Client as GoutteClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;


$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array('defaults' => array(
     'allow_redirects' => false,
     'cookies' => false
));
$client = new GoutteClient();
$client->setClient($guzzleClient);

$client->request('GET', 'http://example.org');
```